# Read data from text file with php and create database

Tags: php, logging, text-files

I have a text file, a huge one that contains some information's that I need to insert into a database.

Here is the one of the rows of the text file:

```
 77.242.22.86 - - [10/Jul/2013:14:07:26 +0200] "GET /web/img/theimage.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://www.mywebiste.com/web/"
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
 Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.1"
```

I am using some php functions like:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
```

This only read the text file, as I said, I need to get the data and insert into the database, here is an example how I need the row to be spli:

```
 77.242.22.86
 [10/Jul/2013:14:07:26 +0200] 
 GET 
 /web/img/theimage.jpg 
 HTTP/1.1
 304
 http://www.mywebiste.com/web/ 
 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
 Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.1
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: $test=fread($fh); Now store the $test variable in db or use $test=file_get_contents('file.txt');

Comment: hello, thnx for answer, but i need to insert the data in diferent rows. so i can use them

Comment: my questions is how split the data from text and insert them to the database, the example is showed at the end of the post.

Comment: Ok check whether my answer useful for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
 $test ='77.242.22.86 - - [10/Jul/2013:14:07:26 +0200]
 "GET /web/img/theimage.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://www.mywebiste.com/web/"
 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
 Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.1"';    
 function tokenizer($test) {
 $test = trim(strtolower($test));
 $res=  str_replace(",","",$test);
 $res=  str_replace("-","",$res);
 $res=  str_replace(' "',"",$res);
 $result=  explode(" ", $res);
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
 $result[$i] = trim($result[$i]);
 echo $result[$i]; ?>

 <hr/> <?php

 }
 return $result; // contains the single words
 }
```

Comment: Here is what i have wrote.
$myFile = "mytexttt.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$test=fread($fh)

function Split($test) 
{
    $test = trim(strtolower($test));
    preg_split('/((^\p{P}+)|(\p{P}*\s+\p{P}*)|(\p{P}+$))/', $test, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) 
    {
     $result[$i] = trim($result[$i]);
    }
     return $result; // contains the single words
}
i get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7

Comment: HERE IS the error
Warning: fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 5

Comment: Try this updated answer and could you show me your fread() function.

Comment: $test = fread($fh,2500); it give a lot of results, but it is not divided in the way i need.

Comment: In what way you need and how it got Splitted?

Comment: it slpit every thing, what about to put a <hr/> when the new row starts? can u help for this?

Comment: Now I have Splitted the words by space,before i have splitted the words by symbols,Now can u say what do u want as a delimiter to split the words?Do u want to Insert the result in db or do u want to print it?

Comment: i can insert the results in database, the problem is that with the script u have created, i cant determinate when the line at the text file finish, because i need to know when a new line will start. idk if i am clear, my english is not so good, thnx for helping.